# Generate.jks file with .crt file and ca signed certificate

Tags: ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate

I newer to configure SSL setup
I have .crt file and
CA signed files

1. Root CA Certificate
2. Intermediate CA Certificate
3. Intermediate CA Certificate
4. Your PositiveSSL Certificate

How should I create .jks file from the above files.I checked alot but didn't work for me
Can anyone help me out
or
I need to configure tomcat with ssl is there any other way to configure without .jks file please let me know

Comment: An SSL/TLS server like Tomcat **requires a certificate/chain AND MATCHING PRIVATE KEY**. When you, or somebody, submitted the CSR to Sectigo-was-Comodo you/they had the privatekey. If you/they destroyed it, you're out of luck. If you/they have it, use it. Often the privatekey was created IN a Java keystore file, which means you/they already have a keystore and don't need to create one, only to merge the certificate chain into it. For Tomcat 8.5 and 9.0 you can configure using PEM file formats instead of a keystore, but you always need both cert/chain and privatekey regardless of format.

Comment: I don't have a separate private key I have a .csr that I generate from KeyPair.Co incident I the key pair is not saved into the machine. but I have a .csr that I Upload to CA.
Is this will works.or their anything works around for I am new to it. please suggest
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what 'generate from KeyPair.Co incident' means, but if you generated the CSR and keypair together and did not save the keypair, you're out of luck. Without the keypair (and specifically the privatekey) the certificate cannot be used, ever, full stop.